# Having error if the value or the ajax result is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

My problem is when `emp_presentEmployment` field is empty my ajax script is not working but if i put value on it in the database my code work.

Can anyone help me how to fix this kind of error?

**problem**:

```
$('.prof_presentEmployed[value='+result.emp_presentEmployment+']').prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
```

**script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pro_empinfo, #pro_empinfo1, #pro_empinfo2, #pro_empinfo3, #pro_empinfo4, #pro_empinfo5').click(function() {

        var data = {};
        data.emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Oppa/view/viewEmployment.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(result) {

                $('.prof_employed[value=' + result.emp_currentlyEmployed + ']').prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
                $('.prof_presentEmployed[value=' + result.emp_presentEmployment + ']').prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
                $("#prof_officeName").val(result.emp_officeName);
                $("#prof_officeAddress").val(result.emp_officeAddress);
                $("#prof_jobPosition").val(result.emp_jobPosition);
                $("#prof_noYearsInPosition").val(result.emp_noOfYearsinPresentJob);
                $("#prof_noYearsInGovPosition").val(result.emp_totalYearsinGovernmentService);
                $("#prof_statusOfEmployment").val(result.emp_statusOfEmployment);
                $(".show-page[data-page=Profile_Employment_info]").trigger("click");

            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check for the property existence before trying to use it, and make sure it is not empty. You need to check empty because the way you have the selector, an empty value ends up making the selector an invalid expression which is why you got the unrecognized expression error.

```
if(result.emp_presentEmployment !== undefined && result.emp_presentEmployment != ""){
    $('.prof_presentEmployed[value=' + result.emp_presentEmployment + ']').prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: You can just do `if(result.emp_presentEmployment){`

Comment: @AndreiDvoynos, except that if a legitimate value was say `0` (a falsy value) the block would be skipped cause it would see it as false

Comment: You're correct, i guessed i assumed it would be a string value on the property

Comment: In this particular case it might be but others might see this answer and their values might include 0 or other falsy type values, which is why i wrote it like that so that both will benefit :)